# How can I iterate through this Perl structure?

Tags: arrays, perl, printing, hash, reference

Given the following code, I'm trying to figure out how to iterate through the array of hash references (or at least I think it's an array of hash refs).  That is, the `$Policy->rules()`?

Perhaps there is a better way of creating an array of structures, I'm open to suggestions.

```
use Class::Struct;
use Data::Dumper;

struct Policy => {         
    listings    => '@',  # Will treat like rules eventually.     
    rules       => '@',  # an array of rules      
};

struct Rule => {                
    direction   => '$',        
    id          => '$',        
};

$policy = Policy->new();

$rule1 = Rule->new();
$rule1->direction('Any');
$rule1->id(1);

$rule2 = Rule->new();
$rule2->direction('Inbound');
$rule2->id(2);

$rule3 = Rule->new();
$rule3->direction('Outbound');
$rule3->id(3);

push($policy->rules(),$rule1);
push($policy->rules(),$rule2);
push($policy->rules(),$rule3);

$Data::Dumper::Indent = $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
print Dumper \$policy;
```

Output:

```
\bless( {
    'Policy::listings' => [],
    'Policy::rules' => [
      bless( {
        'Rule::id' => 1,
        'Rule::direction' => 'Any'
      }, 'Rule' ),
      bless( {
        'Rule::id' => 2,
        'Rule::direction' => 'Inbound'
      }, 'Rule' ),
      bless( {
        'Rule::id' => 3,
        'Rule::direction' => 'Outbound'
      }, 'Rule' )
    ]
  }, 'Policy' )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
visit_policy($policy);

sub visit_policy {
   my ($policy) = @_;

   my $listings = $policy->listings;
   my $rules    = $policy->rules;

   for my $listing (@$listings) {
      visit_listing($listing);
   }

   for my $rule (@$rules) {
      visit_rule($rule);
   }
}

sub visit_listing {
   my ($listing) = @_;
   # ...
}

sub visit_rule {
   my ($rule) = @_;

   my $direction = $rule->direction;
   my $id        = $rule->id;

   # ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.  I had to tweak it a tad.  Visit_listing() was being called 2x.  After changing the visit_rule to get $rule->direction and $rule->id, I get the following error when it tries to defref the $rule->direction:Can't call method "direction" on unblessed reference at line 66.

Comment: Applied the fixes you mention. Tested it. Don't get the error you get, nor does it make sense with the information you provided.

Comment: How do I get the referenced blessed?

Comment: Here is what I am running:  visit_policy($policy);

sub visit_policy {
   my ($policy) = @_;

   my $listings = $policy->listings;
   my $rules    = $policy->rules;

   for my $listing (@$listings) {
      visit_listing($listing);
   }

   for my $rule (@$rules) {
      visit_rule($rules);
   }
}

sub visit_listing {
   my ($listing) = @_;
   # ...
}

sub visit_rule {
   my ($rule) = @_;

   my $direction = $rule->direction;
   my $id        = $rule->id;

 print $id . "\n";

   # ...
}

Comment: I got it.  You were right.  I did jack it up some how.  I started over and now it works perfectly.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help.  It looks close, but it still needs a few tweeks.  See below.  Now when I run it and try to print the rule->id I get the following:

Can't call method "direction" on unblessed reference at D:/SLC/Aiken/Policy/POC/OLAP/test.pl line 66.

```
visit_policy($policy);

sub visit_policy {
   my ($policy) = @_;

   my $listings = $policy->listings;
   my $rules    = $policy->rules;

   for my $listing (@$listings) {
      visit_listing($listing);
   }

   for my $rule (@$rules) {
      visit_rule($rules);
   }
}

sub visit_listing {
   my ($listing) = @_;
   # ...
}

sub visit_rule {
   my ($rule) = @_;

   my $direction = $rule->direction;  #<-- Line 66 
   my $id        = $rule->id;

    print $id . "\n";

   # ...
}
```